# flutter UI : How to create Tracking order UI?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to create Order tracking UI , But I am not usnderstanding that how to create this.

This is my UI ,I want to create UI like this.

[image]

Comment: [TimelineTile](https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_tile)  will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) widget.
Example from doc

```dart
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stepper(
      currentStep: _index,
      onStepCancel: () {
      },
      onStepContinue: () {
      },
      onStepTapped: (int index) {
      },
      steps: <Step>[
        Step(
          title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
          content: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: const Text('Content for Step 1')),
        ),
        const Step(
          title: Text('Step 2 title'),
          content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Also check [im_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) for show tracking detail of your order.